# How to get a unique and short labelname with biblatex?

Tags: biblatex

Consider this MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}[force]{\jobname.bib}
@book{Lazarenko2013,
   author   = {Lazarenko, Igor and Mircheva, Elina and Encheva, Radostina and Stoyanova, Daniela and Sharankov, Nikolay},
   title    = {The Temple of the Pontic Mother of Gods in Dionysopolis},
   date     = {2013},
   location = {Varna},
}

@incollection{Lazarenko2010,
   author    = {Lazarenko, Igor and Mircheva, Elina and Encheva, Radostina and Sharankov, Nikolaj},
   title     = {The Temple of the Pontic Mother of Gods in Dionysopolis},
   date      = {2010},
   booktitle = {Ancient Sacral Monuments in the Black Sea},
   editor    = {Petropoulos, Elias K. and Maslennikov, Alexander A.},
   location  = {Thessaloniki},
   pages     = {13--62},
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=biber,
   citestyle   = ext-authoryear
  ,bibstyle    = ext-authortitle
  ,isbn        = false
  ,introcite   = label
  ,dashed      = false
  ,articlein   = false
  ,sorting     = nyt
  % ,maxnames    = 2
  % ,minnames    = 1
  % ,uniquename=full
  ,maxbibnames = 999
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The output is

[image]

I would like to have short but unique labelname - in this case it should be `Lazarenko 2010` and `Lazarenko 2013`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what exactly short but unique means for you your mileage may vary.

You will definitely want to look into **the `uniquelist` option**. With `uniquelist=false,` you can stop `biblatex` trying to make the author lists unique so that with the appropriate `(min|max)citenames` values we get "Lazarenko et al. 2010" and "Lazarenko et al. 2013". The `uniquelist` option also has the option `minyear` that would expand the lists again if the two works were from the same year. More about `uniquelist` can be found on p. 68 and in §4.11.4 *Name Disambiguation* of [the `biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf).

Many people who set `uniquelist=false,` also want to set `uniquename=false,` (the `uniquename` option has more possible values that are explained with examples(!) in the documentation).

If you want to get rid of the "et al." as well (which I don't recommend), you will need the option `nohashothers=true,` to make sure an `extradate` value is generated if necessary. You will probably also want to set `nosortothers=true,` to avoid counter-intuitive sorting results. With those option set, you can set out to suppress "et al.". This is best done by redefining the `labeldate` format (the original definition can be found [in ll. 933-960 of `biblatex.def` (v3.14)](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/2ddd2836927d08ac600c8fa3af1897417548ac05/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def#L933-L960)). See also https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/861.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
   citestyle    = ext-authoryear
  ,bibstyle     = ext-authortitle
  ,isbn         = false
  ,introcite    = label
  ,dashed       = false
  ,articlein    = false
  ,sorting      = nyt
  ,maxcitenames = 2
  ,mincitenames = 1
  ,uniquelist   = false
  ,uniquename   = false
  ,nohashothers = true
  ,nosortothers = true
  ,maxbibnames  = 999
]{biblatex}

\DeclareNameFormat{labelname}{%
  \ifcase\value{uniquename}%
    \usebibmacro{name:family}
      {\namepartfamily}
      {\namepartgiven}
      {\namepartprefix}
      {\namepartsuffix}%
  \or
    \ifuseprefix
      {\usebibmacro{name:given-family}
        {\namepartfamily}
        {\namepartgiveni}
        {\namepartprefix}
        {\namepartsuffixi}}
      {\usebibmacro{name:given-family}
        {\namepartfamily}
        {\namepartgiveni}
        {\namepartprefixi}
        {\namepartsuffixi}}%
  \or
    \usebibmacro{name:given-family}
      {\namepartfamily}
      {\namepartgiven}
      {\namepartprefix}
      {\namepartsuffix}%
  \fi}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Lazarenko2013,
  author   = {Lazarenko, Igor and Mircheva, Elina
              and Encheva, Radostina and Stoyanova, Daniela
              and Sharankov, Nikolay},
  title    = {The Temple of the Pontic Mother of Gods in Dionysopolis},
  date     = {2013},
  location = {Varna},
}
@incollection{Lazarenko2010,
  author    = {Lazarenko, Igor and Mircheva, Elina
               and Encheva, Radostina and Sharankov, Nikolaj},
  title     = {The Temple of the Pontic Mother of Gods in Dionysopolis},
  date      = {2010},
  booktitle = {Ancient Sacral Monuments in the Black Sea},
  editor    = {Petropoulos, Elias K. and Maslennikov, Alexander A.},
  location  = {Thessaloniki},
  pages     = {13--62},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lazarenko 2010//Lazarenko 2013]